# How to Add all elements of a python list

Tags: python, arraylist

So basically I have a List inputed by the user, I check if all the elements are positive I output all positive, if they are all negative i output all negative, but if they are both pos and negative i need to sum them all up and I dont know how to do this last step, This is my code until now

```
stop = "0"
Numbers = []
number = ""
while number != stop:
    number  = input("enter a number ")
    Numbers.append(number)
    print(Numbers)
if all(int(element) >= 0 for element in Numbers):
    print("allpos")
if all(int(element) <= 0 for element in Numbers):
    print("all neg")
```

Comment: do a small chage. Keep first if, instead of second if write elif, and then add else statement, which would be sum(Numbers) and that's it.

Answer (score 3):

Use `sum`.

```
print(sum(numbers))
```

Also, use lowercase characters for variable names.

```
stop="0"
number =""
numbers=[]
while number != stop:
    number = input("enter a number ")
    numbers.append(int(number))
print(numbers)
if all(element > 0 for element in numbers):
    print("allpos")
elif all(element < 0 for element in numbers):
    print("all neg")
else:
    print(sum(numbers))
```

Or clearer approach:

```
numbers = [int(x) for x in input("enter list of numbers, separated by space: ").split()]
print(numbers)
if all(element > 0 for element in numbers):
    print("allpos")
elif all(element < 0 for element in numbers):
    print("all neg")
else:
    print(sum(numbers))
```

Comment: I tried it and it's giving me a TypeError unsupported operand types for + 'int' and 'str' help please

Comment: Before summing you need to be sure the elements are numeric.
You should filter non numeric before adding to numbers.

Comment: but im only inputting numbers like 5, -2 , 1.... stuff like that, im a complete noob here so sorry if this sounds dumb so how do i fix this

Comment: Yes @Tombrown you should convert input string to int, I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this:

```
list_ = [1, 2, -3]

if all(int(element) >= 0 for element in list_):
    print("allpos")

elif all(int(element) <= 0 for element in list_):
    print("all neg")

else: 
    print('sum', sum(list_))
```

Comment: It's giving me a TypeError unsupported operan types for + 'int' and 'str' what do i do

Comment: It's because you have mixed data types in your list. You need to either fitler out only numeric values, or convert string digits to numeric type.

Comment: but im only inputting numbers like 5, -2 , 1.... stuff like that, im a complete noob here so sorry if this sounds dumb so how do i fix this